# Regarding Diff of two changelist and Backout History

Tags: perforce

In my project we have three different branches where code resides.
I am giving name 1st, 2nd, 3rd as branch names. 1st is the starting brach of any code and merge happens to 2nd from 1st and to 3rd from 2nd.

**Queries**

1. How to get difference between two changelist given that-
   a. Both changelist belong to same branch.
   b. Both changelist belong to different branches lets say 1st and 2nd.
2. For a given changelist, is there any way to know if that changelist was ever backed out or rollbacked?

Answer (score 0):

1a) `p4 diff2 //depot/branch/...@CHANGE1 //depot/branch/...@CHANGE2`

1b) `p4 diff2 //depot/branch1/...@CHANGE1 //depot/branch2/...@CHANGE2`

2) If you used the `p4 undo` command:
   `p4 filelog @=CHANGE` (look for "undone by" in the history)

If you used P4V or some other method: no.